# How to amend an amended return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, amended-tax-return

I made a real mess of my taxes this year.  I filed an amended return with the IRS that turned out to be incorrect.  The amended return included a sale of restricted stock units.  Unfortunately, I got the cost basis wrong.  The taxes were paid at the grant time, so the cost basis should've been the same as the final sale price, but I mistakenly listed the cost bases as 0 dollars.  I got a letter from the IRS saying that I owe an additional $500 dollars due by April 27th.  This amount is consistent with the amended return that I filed.  The letter says that I can write back to the IRS and contest the amount if I believe it to be incorrect, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

1. Write back to the IRS and explain that the amended return was incorrect - my taxes were right the first time. - I don't believe it's possible to withdraw an amended return though
2. File a 2nd amended return that corrects the mistake I made on the 1st amended return

There's a 2nd orthogonal decision I have to make too:

1. Pay the $500 before April 27th and try to get it back later
2. Don't pay the $500 because I don't actually owe the IRS that money

What is the correct action here?  Should I write a letter contesting the amount?  Should I file a 2nd amended return?  Both?  Do I pay the $500 before April 27th?  Is it possible to withdraw an amended return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> File a 2nd amended return that corrects the mistake I made on the 1st amended return

This.

> Pay the $500 before April 27th and try to get it back later

This.