# How do I amend an amended tax return?

Tags: income-tax, new-york, amended-tax-return

I filed my taxes early this year. Then I realized I forgot a W-2. TurboTax told me they weren't ready to process amendments yet, but I was impatient. I found a way to fill out an amendment form, so I did. Only after I mailed it in did I realize the form was in fact for tax year 2014, not 2015. The data on the form is all correct for 2015, but it has the wrong year at the top (part of the form, not something I entered).

I made this mistake with both my federal and state return.

Before I call the federal & state tax agencies to try and sort this out, is there a standard procedure I should follow?

I noticed there's a very similar question here: [How to amend an amended return?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/46670/how-to-amend-an-amended-return?rq=1) but in that case, the error was not with the form itself. When I check my amended return status on irs.gov, it tells me they have received and are processing an amended return for tax year 2014 (only). This makes me think if I file one for 2015, it will not affect the one for 2014, so I'm hoping for a different answer that addresses that specific concern.

Comment: I suspect you need to re-amend your 2014 return to put it back to what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can amend an amended return the same as the original. The IRS will keep each version of your taxes submitted.

However, I think you need to call and speak to an agent in both tax agencies. You have effectively amended a return for a previous tax year with a document for the current tax year. An agent might be able to remove the amended return without having to refile.

Regardless, you should ensure your 2014 taxes are not wrong now. (I would be very surprised if your 2014 and 2015 numbers are identical.) If anything you accidentally submitted to your 2014 carries forward to 2015, you have probably affected your 2015 filing as well because your numbers carrying forward between the amended 2014 and non-amended 2015 will not add up.

Comment: My numbers for 2014 and 2015 are starkly different since I was employed full-time at a single job for most of 2014, and spent most of 2015 freelancing for a number of different clients in addition to holding a few temporary full-time gigs, so any inconsistencies should be very obvious...but I don't know how these things are processed so maybe I'm assuming too much.

Comment: My understanding is most of it is machine processed. Therefore, the numbers reported will become your new numbers for 2014, and if you reported less income you might already have an additional refund check on the way, or you might have a letter demanding more payment with penalties and interest. Regardless, if it is still in processing it might not be too late. Speak to an agent about it. You need your old numbers back on the 2014 file to avoid the tax aggravations that will follow.

Answer (score -1):

Normally you would amend an amended tax return the same way as you amend an unamended one.

However, because you sent your amendment *before* they were ready to accept amendments (which takes about a day after e-filing), it is unclear if your amendment was ever accepted or not. Either way, you just amend again, but I recommend to make your amendment now so that it covers the first *and* the second change (so it contains the first change *again*), in case ithat one was never accepted.